# How to remotely connect to tomcat 8 on a Linux server

Tags: java, linux, remote-access, vps, tomcat8

I've been trying to remotely connect to Tomcat Manager (Version 8.0.21) installed on a VPS machine that uses Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I can access it from inside the VPS through both local host (`http://localhost:8080`) and IP Address  (`http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:8080`) but when I try to access it from another machine using server's public ip address the request just times out. I did a lot of research and already tried a few things listed below but none of them worked:

- Tomcat configuration files(server.xml)
  - Add both address="0.0.0.0" and address="xxx.xxx.x.xx" to all connectors
  - Add resolveHosts="true" to all Valve tags
  - Add JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true" on catalina.sh file
- VPS machine configuraion
  - Enable firewall and allow connections on ports 80, 8080, and 22
  - Temporarily disable firewall
  - Disable IPv6

Comment: Most likely, your server has an RFC 1918 address (10/8, 127.16/12, or 192.168/16).  These are not directly accessible from a public IP.  Configure your router to forward a public IP port to the machine (which can use a different port).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, and correct me if Im wrong  but I dont think the   address is a private one since I have remote access through port 22 via SSH

Comment: The "times out" indicates a packet is being dropped.  Use tcpdump on the router and server to see where the packet is dropped.